# How to set Android BottomNavigationView's item's color to be selected status, after replacing menus with custom view?

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

When I use default `BottomNavigationView`, the first item's color is `status_selected` one as intended. However, when I replace menu's `View` with custom view, even though the first `Fragment` is created as intended, `menuItem` on the `BottomNavigationView`'s color is not-selected one.

I want the first `menuItem`'s appearance to be `status_selected`. Is there any solution I can apply?

`BottomNavigationView` is on the Fragment (parent one), and I apply setting custom view as follows:

#### MainFragment.kt

```
override fun onCreateView(
  inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
  _binding = FragmentMainBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    .apply {
      setBottomNavigation(bottomNaviView)
    }
  return binding.root
}

private fun setBottomNavigation(bottomNavView: BottomNavigationView) = bottomNavView.run {
  val menus = menu
  for (i in 0 until menus.size) {
    val item = menus.getItem(i)
    replaceBottomNavItemWithCustomView(this, item)
  }
  setOnItemSelectedListener(navItemSelectListener)
}

private fun replaceBottomNavItemWithCustomView(bottomNavView: BottomNavigationView, item: MenuItem) {
  val itemView = bottomNavView.findViewById<View>(item.itemId) as ViewGroup
  val customView = LayoutInflater.from(requireContext()).inflate(R.layout.bottom_nav_item, null)
  customView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.icon).setImageDrawable(item.icon)
  customView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.label).text = item.title.toString()
  itemView.removeAllViews()
  itemView.addView(customView)
}
```

What I've tried:

1. `binding.bottomNaviView.menu.getItem(0).isChecked = true` at `onViewCreated`
2. added below code at `replaceBottomNavItemWithCustomView` function :

```
customView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.icon).run {
  imageTintList = item.iconTintList
  setImageDrawable(item.icon)
  if (item.itemId == R.id.first_item_id) item.isChecked = true
}
customView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.label).run {
  setTextColor(item.iconTintList)
  text = item.title.toString()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After tried many attempts, I found an answer, which is so simple that I became ashamed of why I couldn't come up with this much earlier.

just add `customView.isSelected = item.isChecked` and all goes fine.